# Does cql support python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, thrift, cql

Does cql has support python3?

I tried to install with pip but it failed.

```
rabit@localhost:/usr/bin> pip-3.3 install cql
^CDownloading/unpacking cql
Operation cancelled by user
Storing complete log in /home/rabit/.pip/pip.log
rabit@localhost:/usr/bin> sudo pip-3.3 install cql
root's password:
Downloading/unpacking cql
  Downloading cql-1.4.0.tar.gz (76kB): 76kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package cql

Downloading/unpacking thrift (from cql)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package thrift
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build/thrift/setup.py", line 45
        except DistutilsPlatformError, x:
                                     ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build/thrift/setup.py", line 45

    except DistutilsPlatformError, x:

                                 ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build/thrift
```

In fact cql is dependent on Thrift which probably not support python3

Any solution??

Comment: "It failed" is not a useful error description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thrift does indeed explicitly not support Python 3, it's metadata is marked as supporting Python 2 only, and installing it gives you a Syntax error.

The solution is to contact the authors of Thrift and help them [port to Python 3](http://python3porting.com/). and once that is done, help port cql. Updating is usually easy (except in some special cases) and fun!

Comment: Nice subtle link to your own book there, Lennart. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. :-) It is the best resource, and free! :-)

Answer (score 4):

No, the `cql` library is **not** compatible with Python 3. It relies on `thrift`, a package that is *not* Python 3 compatible itself:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.3/build/thrift/setup.py", line 45
    except DistutilsPlatformError, x:
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`cql` itself uses the same obsolete syntax in `cqltypes.py`:

```
except (ValueError, AssertionError, IndexError), e:
```

Both `thrift` and `cql` need to be ported first.

Answer (score -1):

For Python 3, you can use [CQLEngine](https://github.com/cqlengine/cqlengine).